# Cleaning phone number

Tags: python, data-cleaning

I want to create a function where I can pass list of phone number then return list of cleaned phone number.

Valid phone number should start with `62` and must be 11-digit number excluding 62. If after cleansing, there is still an invalid phone number, change it to Invalid Number.

Here is the phone list

```
phone = [
    '82123321123',
    '082321123321',
    '+6282-456-654-456',
    '+62 82 789 987 789',
    '14045',
    '82145-451-145'
]
```

here is the wanted output:

```
[6282123321123, 6282321123321, 6282456654456, 6282789987789, 'Invalid Number', 6282145451145]
```

This is the code i have tried before, can someone please add the correct code for my case please ..

```
def clean_phone_number(phone):
    adding_62 = "62"
    for index, value in enumerate(phone) :
        phone[index] = adding_62 + value
    for index,value in enumerate (phone) :
        symbols = '+-'
        [item.translate(symbols).strip()for item in phone]
        
    pass
    
phone = ['82123321123',
         '082321123321',
         '+6282-456-654-456',
         '+6282789987789',
         '14045',
         '82145-451-145']
clean_phone_number(phone)
print (phone)
```

Comment: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Phone Numbers](https://github.com/google/libphonenumber/blob/master/FALSEHOODS.md)

Comment: Use regex and lambda function, you will have it easily.

Comment: You don't mention that a (starting) `+` sign is valid, yet your example show it is. Please be clear about what is valid and what not. Similar for spaces and dashes.

Comment: You have a list comprehension but you don't do anything with the list it creates.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it without using RegEx:

```
def clean_phone_number(num):

    num = num.lstrip('+').lstrip('0').replace('-', '')
    if not num.startswith('62'):
        num = '62' + num
    if len(num) != 13 or not num.isdigit():
        num = 'Invalid Number'
    return num

    
phones = ['82123321123',
         '082321123321',
         '+6282-456-654-456',
         '+6282789987789',
         '14045',
         '82145-451-145']

clean_phone_numbers = []
for phone in phones:
    clean_phone_numbers.append(clean_phone_number(phone))

print(clean_phone_numbers)
```

gives:

```
['6282123321123', '6282321123321', '6282456654456', '6282789987789', 'Invalid Number', '6282145451145']
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I got it. Thank you it work well

Comment: Please accept the answer if it resolves your question.

Answer (score 0):

OK this regex should handel your conditions.

```
\+62[0-9]{11}
```

However you need to clean it up, so remove any `spaces` and `-`.

Note `+` by it self is a regex function so you need to escape it by using `\`.
The `[]` show possible values, in this case we are defining a range from ascii '0' to ascii '9' that give you 48 until 57.
Finally the `{}` are the set repeating.

If you don't want to keep the `+` you can use `^` instead of `\+`.
The `^` mean starts with so `^62` literally means it start with "62", you can use `$` to define it ends.

You can use https://regexr.com/ to get a better explanation, and if the numbers are in a file you could just use grep.